# Is there any way to replace text in EditText with spannable, but save value?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

What I have: user see EditText and can input some numbers into it, or push button and some numbers will be insert into EditText. The problem is to replace the numbers with text, but save numeric value.

For example, after press button, application can insert text 123, but this text should be replaced to "For all". I don't wanna just insert text, because Editable.toString() will return that text. I can't insert images like badges, because application is multilanguage, and repainting labels for each language will be too long.

So, can I replace 123 with spannable string "For all", and when user press backspace he will have 12? If it possible, how to do such thing?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes ofcourse, You can!
All you need is data structure & algorithm to convert string from numbers & vice versa. Look for the Android EditText's addTextChangedListener(). This is the place you have to execute your algorithm

Comment: Cool. That is very good news. So how?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with that. I don't know why you need this strange "translation", but anyway - some  questions here: If I'm to input "123" as numbers and I manage to see "For all" as text, when backspacing (in order to receive "12", with the "3" removed) how can I know what I typed?
Can't this be done in two `EditText` fields, the one for `Input` and the other for `Output`? Is it only "123" that you want to be "translated" to "For All" or you have some rules for "translating" numbers to text?

Comment: Yes, I have some rules like Smiley spannables. But I don't need drawables, but text.

Comment: Well, if you share the rules here, it will be easyer, becasue I don't actually see a clear link between "123" and "For All".

Comment: Rules seems like: 0 - favorites, 00 - friends only, 000 - any user

Comment: Well to get the algorithm, For definite you have to share requirement!

Comment: @Manik, my dear friend, it is commercial secret :) I have said more, than allowed :)

Comment: So basically if "0" is typed, you expect to receive "Favourites" as text in the same EditText field, after you press a button or something? This got me interested, but unfortunatelly I don't seem to understand what you need ..

Comment: If that's the case, then you can try: String newString = string.replace("0", "Favourites"); you can put this in a switch structure, to determine, the first string to be replaced. Then just put your hardcoded strings (e.g. like "Favourites" as the second argument). After that update the EditText field.